# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException in Java

Tags: selenium, web, exception, driver

I am new to Automation and trying to learn Automation as a manual tester. I am trying to execute a simple java code to open a Chrome browser using Selenium Webdrivers and get the below exception. Tried all possible ways to resolve the same and still nothing works. Any help would really help. Thanks.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b) on port 3527
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 4.67 seconds
Build info: version: '2.51.0', revision: '1af067d', time: '2016-02-05 19:11:55'
System info: host: 'BTP196816', ip: '10.241.51.20', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.7.0_99'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:116)
    at OpenAdf.LaunchAdf.main(LaunchAdf.java:11)
```

Comment: Some additional information on the versions being used: Chrome Version: 55; Java version: jre 1.7.0_99; Selenium Java version: 2.51; selenium server standlaone 2.51; Chromedriver version: 2.28

Comment: the error said it's not found the chrome binary. You need to give the path of your chrome driver.
String exepath="/home/user/mars workspace/SeleniumTest/chromedriver";
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exepath);

Comment: Instead of providing a string, I have given the same as an argument in the setproperty. But still Ihave tried as you have mentioned but still getting the same error.

Comment: share your code here, what you tried.
If you are using chrome driver of 2.28 version then your chrome browser must be 57+ version.
Check here https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: Hi Hiten, Here is my code that Im trying package OpenAdf;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class LaunchAdf {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\SeleniumDrivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

 }

}

Comment: As I mentioned my Chrome browser is version 55. So Can you let me know which Chromedriver version should I use. I guess it is some issue with the version compatibility only

Comment: try with the chrome driver version of 2.25, 2.26 or 2.27.

Answer (score 0):

try using that :

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\SeleniumDrivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capability.setCapability("binary", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capability);
```

You can also try

```
capability.setCapability("chrome.binary", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a ton Hiten.. It worked. From your above code I understood that Selenium is looking for the Chrome browser in the location: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application" and in my machine the location of Chrome was different. I just manually moved Chrome to the exact location and used my same code and it worked. Thank you so much. This is of so much help. I was struggling with this simple piece since 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\SeleniumDrivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Need to set the chrome driver path and the chrome driver path must be at the location which you gave in the code.